# Correct xpath syntax with pythons lxml library for parsing all the text from arbitrary nested html tags

Tags: python, html, parsing, xpath, lxml

Using lxml in python I created this xpath syntax

```
htmlPage.xpath("/html/body//a/text()")
```

It gets me all  `<a>`-tags in certain html scopes I desire. Now I encountered that the `<a>`-tags could look like this:

```
<a>This is a sentence with some <italic>italic text</italic>-formatting I want to parse.</a>
```

xpath returns me a list that has one element more then I expect. I checked that and recognized, that it splits the `<a>`-tag mentioned above into two list elements, instead of one. Instead of the string

```
"This is a sentence with some italic text-formatting I want to parse."
```

I get the two strings

```
"This is a sentence with some" # and
"-formatting I want to parse."
```

Is there a way to correct that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem by first getting all `<a>`-tags

```
results = htmlPage.xpath("/html/body//a")
```

and then iterating the returned list and using `text_content()` on the list elements

```
for a_tag in results:
    print a_tag.text_content() # prints bthe whol string: "This is a sentence with some italic text-formatting I want to parse."
```